# Ubuntu 14.04 Installation with Preseeded RAID 1 Partitioning

Tags: virtualbox, partition, ubuntu-14.04, raid1, preseed

I have been having a painful time trying to automate an Ubuntu 14.04 Server Installation with RAID 1 partitioning.
I'm testing this on top of VirtualBox with two Virtual Disk Images (dynamically allocated to increase in size up to 1TB) and a custom ISO that I am generating from the preseed.

I'm trying to have a RAID 1 that mirrors two hard disks such that the first 32GB of BOTH 1TB disks is "swap" and the rest of the disk is ext4.
i.e. md0 = sda1 and sdb1 (swap)
md1 = sda2 and sdb2 (ext4).
The problem, however, is that every time I try to do this, I get stuck at the "Partition Disks" manual installation menu and only the sda partition information has been populated (i.e. it will show the swap and ext4).  The sdb partition will be empty and I will have to manually enter the information and generate the partition table from there.
I have tried a wide variety of preseed configurations found online, tinkered with them, and still have had no luck.  Any advice / help is greatly appreciated!  Note: I have used kickstart to surpass some of the initial menus, not sure if this could have interfered somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!

Had a bad recipe that was causing issues.  Hopefully this will be a useful reference for anybody else running into the same problem while trying to build a RAID 1 2 hd partitioned system:

```
## RAID 1 PRESEED
d-i     partman-auto/method string raid

d-i     partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda /dev/sdb
d-i     partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i     partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i     partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i     partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string main_vg

# Next you need to specify the physical partitions that will be used. 
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string           \
    multiraid ::                    \
    200% 512 200% raid            \
        $lvmignore{ }           \
        $primary{ }         \
        method{ raid }          \
        raidid{ 1 }         \
    .                   \
    4000 5000 -1 raid           \
        $lvmignore{ }           \
        method{ raid }          \
        raidid{ 2 }         \
    .

d-i partman-auto-raid/recipe string         \
    1 2 0 swap -                \
    raidid=1                \
    .                       \
    1 2 0 ext4 /                 \
    raidid=2                \
    .

d-i     mdadm/boot_degraded boolean true
d-i     partman-md/confirm boolean true
d-i     partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i     partman/choose_partition select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
d-i     partman/confirm boolean true
d-i     partman-md/confirm_nooverwrite  boolean true
d-i     partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```